# Smarty check if undefined

Tags: php, cakephp, smarty, template-engine

i am getting errors if smarty variable is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
< input type="text" value="{$data.allKeywords} id='keyId' />
```

I am getting the error: Undefined index: allKeywords.

I know the variable - $data.allKeywords is undefined but should it not ignore it if a variable is undefined?

Is there a way to check if it is undefined in smarty template files only ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it in a [Smarty if statement](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.if.php)

```
<input type="text" value="{if $data.allKeywords}{$data.allKeywords}{/if} "id='keyId' />
```

Comment: thanks Mike. but it is the same error. looks like i need something like isset to first check of a variable exists.

Comment: You can do if isset() in smarty.

Comment: But do you know if there is a way to consider the value of a variable null , if it is undefined in smarty?

Comment: @Ron, you can do is_null in smarty too

Comment: There seems to be a quote missing? (probably after the `{/if}`)